# ElasticSearch container won't start up in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-image

I'm attempting to run this script in Win10 to configure everything.
All containers except the elastic container are initialized correctly and
Elastic times out and then exits with code 124.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GauT5.jpg (some log outputs)
[image: some log outputs]
[image: some log outputs]
I'm running this script where I didn't touch anything except the Windows ports (you can see the comments)
    https://pastebin.com/7Z8Gnenr

```
version: '3.1'

# Generated on 23-04-2018

services:
  alfresco:
    image: openmbeeguest/mms-repo:3.2.4-SNAPSHOT
    environment:
      CATALINA_OPTS: "-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - activemq
      - elastic
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - alf_logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs
      - alf_data:/opt/alf_data
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
      - /usr/local/tomcat/temp/
      - /usr/local/tomcat/work/

  solr:
    image: openmbeeguest/mms-solr:3.2.4-SNAPSHOT
    environment:
      CATALINA_OPTS: "-Xmx1G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8m -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200"
    depends_on:
      - alfresco
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - solr_logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/
      - solr_content_store:/opt/solr/ContentStore
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
      - /usr/local/tomcat/temp/
      - /usr/local/tomcat/work/

  activemq:
    image: openmbeeguest/mms-activemq:3.2.4-SNAPSHOT
    ports:

    #I changed these Windows side ports 
      - 61615:61616 
      - 61617:61614
      - 8162:8161

    # ORIGINAL  
      #- 61616:61616 
      #- 61614:61614
      #- 8161:8161
    volumes:
      - activemq-data-volume:/data/activemq
      - activemq-log-volume:/var/log/activemq
      - activemq-conf-volume:/opt/activemq/conf
    environment:
      - ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_LOGIN admin
      - ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD admin
    networks:
      - internal


  elastic:
    image: openmbeeguest/mms-elastic:3.2.4-SNAPSHOT
    environment:
      CLEAN: 'false'
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elastic-data-volume:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - internal

  postgresql:
    image: openmbeeguest/mms-postgres:3.2.4-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
       - pgsql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=alfresco
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=alfresco
      - POSTGRES_DB=alfresco
    networks:
      - internal


volumes:
  alf_logs:
  alf_data:
  solr_logs:
  solr_content_store:
  pgsql_data:
  activemq-data-volume:
  activemq-log-volume:
  activemq-conf-volume:
  elastic-data-volume:
  nginx-external-volume:

networks:
  internal:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: displayed images, inserted full script

Comment: Please post formatted text, not pictures of formatted text.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the logs from the elasticsearch container to share? Without that it's hard to tell why it's exiting.

One thing that's tripped me up repeatedly though is the `vm.max_map_count` setting - the [default in Docker is too low for elasticsearch to function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode), so it's a good first thing to check.

Comment: Here are my logs
https://pastebin.com/kJCq2n0E

I see nothing related to vm.max_map_count

It definitely isn't a port issue as port 9200 (the one associated with elastic isn't being used.

https://imgur.com/a/ThahwYh

Comment: I am using Win10 and according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966083/docker-machine-no-machine-name-no-default-exists
------
"Docker team want you use Docker for Windows like a regular docker in Linux and don't bother about virtual machine stuff."
------
Should I even try creating a docker-machine then? If so, what parameters would I feed "docker-machine create ......"?